# Creation of a stored procedure requires a package in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, package, public-members

Below is some PL/SQL which is intended to create a very simple stored procedure in Oracle, based on code generated via **SQL Developer IDE**.  I'm receiving the error when I run the command.  On many tutorials online, the instructions for creating stored procedures didn't require a package (in the source code).  When is a package required in Oracle?  And how can I correct the code below to be as simple as possible?

**Source Code:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1
IS
BEGIN

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World!');

END;
```

**Error:**

> Empty package PROCEDURE1 definition (no public members).

FYI:

Before running the code above, I was following these instructions to build a simple example of a stored procedure and connect via Enterprise Library.  This code worked.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19581/Microsoft-Enterprise-Library-Data-Access-Block-DAA

Comment: i've run your code in sql developer and it compiles correctly. You certainly don't need to have a package in order to have a procedure. I would look at your IDE for the problem as your PL/SQL code looks find.

Comment: [this](https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2015/03/19/sqldeveloper-bug-not-showing-plsql-procedures-that-have-no-input-parameters/) could be relevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Workflow to Avoid the error:

When using SQL Developer IDE for Oracle, right click "{Database Name} > Procedures > New Procedure" in the object explorer, and click OK to that dialog after entering a stored procedure name, click the **two gears (Compile)** button.

### Note

The Green Triangle button is used to run the compiled procedure, but it needs to be compiled before you can run it.

Answer (score 1):

**Workflow to reproduce the error:**

When using **SQL Developer IDE** for Oracle, when right clicking "{Database Name} > Procedures > New Procedure" in the object explorer, and clicking OK to that dialog after entering a stored procedure name, and clicking the green triangle (execute) button, I get this error.

**Solution:**

I right clicked the {Database Name} and selected "Open SQL Worksheet" and then pasted the code generated from the workflow above.  Then clicked the green triangle (execute) button.

> What a piece of *HIT IDE!
>
> "I SLIT A SHEET"
>
> "A SHEET I SLIT"
>
> "AND ON THAT SLITTED SHEET I SIT"